# PHP getting data from SQL from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Hey I'm wanting to retrieve some data from the a database. But it seems whenever I enter my credentials into the SQL database to retrieve the data I get the following error:

Comment: At the very least, you could identify which line is 39.

Comment: Where is $connect?? Why using md5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i presume this is a similar use case as your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202220/php-inputing-data-from-form-into-sql-database)

Your php file is missing the configuration of the connection:

```
<?php
$dbuser = "******"; 
$dbpass = "*******"; 
$db = "SSID";
$connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);



if (!$connect) {
echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
exit;
}
```

So it knows which connection you are using and passing to the `checkUserPass()` function.

**UPDATE:**

For the table name you need to pass $dbtable as you can see in the function declaration

> function checkUserPass($connect,$username, $password, **$dbtable**)

so either set a $dbtable variable before calling the function:

> $dbtable="register_table";

or send it immediately as a string:

> function checkUserPass($connect,$username, $password, **"register_table"**)

Comment: ok thanks again for that. I'm still having some errors but I think you've put me on the right track.

Comment: I know this isn't you job and its okay if you CBF. But I'm getting the errors: ociexecute() ORA-00903: invalid table name on line 37 where there seems to be no code on that line?   Also i'm getting one other error of: ocifetch() ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch on line 39 :/

Comment: I updated the question to address this but i suggest you read some beginner tutorials on PHP/MySQL before moving on with development.